# How to extract zip from client in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unzip, postman

I'm having a node app which needs to get some zip file from client **Postman** and extract it to a folder in my fileSystem,Im using **express** I did the following which doesnt work,

what am I missing here?

I've created sample node app to simulate the issue.

```
var express = require('express');
var upload = require('multer')({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var admZip = require('adm-zip');
var app = express();

app.post('/',upload.single('file'),function(req,res){
    debugger;
    var zip = new admZip(req.file);
    zip.extractAllTo("C://TestFolder//TestPathtoExtract", true);
    res.send("unzip");

});

var server = app.listen(3001,function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s',host,port);
})
```

This is how I use it im postman

[image]

If there is other way to do it with **different open source** this can be great!
I use 
https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip

which can be change to any other library

I've also find this lib but not sure how to use it with **express**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/decompress-zip

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: @Michelem -  
its not working Im not getting the file in the req (express) and its not saved,any idea or other solution which can help?

Comment: @Michelem - you can test my code as-is just create server js and paste the conde and run it and use postman to send a zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the set up I did for `Postman`, first this is my `form-data` body

[image: form]

Now in the header I left in blank after trying to set `multipart/form-data` manually and utterly failed, so no header here.

[image: headers]

Here I did a pair of `console.log`, one of `req.headers` to be sure of `Postman` sending the right `multipart/form-data` and another of `req.file`

[image: file]

And well the output seems to be fine

[image]

**Edit:** the code.

```
var express = require('express');
var upload = require('multer')({
  dest: 'uploads/'
});
var admZip = require('adm-zip');
var app = express();

app.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  console.log('%c > req.headers test.js [9] <=================================', 'color:blue;', req.headers);
  debugger;
  console.log('%c > req.file test.js [10] <=================================', 'color:blue;', req.file);
  //instead of just req.file I use req.file.path as admzip needs the actual file path
  var zip = new admZip(req.file.path);
  zip.extractAllTo("/Users/myuser/Desktop/ext", true);
  res.send("unzip");

});

var server = app.listen(3001, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Thanks 1+ for support ! two things1. did you see that the zip file which you provided is extracted in your c folder? 2. does the code is exactly the same with the code i provided in the question? 3.are you working on windows(I ask it since I need some hints this is strange why its not working for me)

Comment: 0. you're welcome! :)
1. indeed the file got extracted
2. I just changed what @HireS. pointed out `req.file.path`(and well the extraction path as I'm not running windows)
3. not really, I'm using OSX

Comment: Can you please post your code also? can you please elborate why you change the "I just changed what @HireS. pointed out req.file.path" Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass filename as argument.

Use `req.file.path`

```
  var zip = new admZip(req.file.path);
```

Comment: do you mean for my case it should be req.test2.zip?

Comment: just paste above code, and if you get error with that then, please show me log of console.log(req.file);

Comment: with the console.log(req.file); I got undefined

Comment: you can test my code as-is just create server.js put the code inside and run it and use postman to send a zip file

Comment: @JohnJerrby shouldn't be `req.files.yourforminputfilename`? or just `console.log(req.files)` and see if you file is in there. btw didn't you asked this before? The question got removed though. EDIT: but well upload single should do the trick

Comment: @HirenS. - can you send screen shot what you have put in postman? and the adopted code?maybe I miss something small...

Comment: @mithril_knight - did you try the code which I post ? is it working for you as-is?

Comment: @JohnJerrby doesn't work for me either, `req.file` got undefined

Comment: @JohnJerrby check the headers your are sending with `postman` in my case with `CocoaRestClient` was by default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and must be `multipart/form-data`. Per multer documentation `NOTE: Multer will not process any form which is not multipart (multipart/form-data).` and don't forget using `req.file.path` as @HirenS. says

Comment: @mithril_knight - can you please send it as answer with some screen shot since Im not sure that I fully got what need to be done(im new to this topice) this could be the right answer how to make it really work...Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mithril_knight -when click on form-data (like in the screen shot I provided) and choose a file and put in the headers Content-Type ->multipart/form-data I got error Error: Multipart: Boundary not found,what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mithril_knight - if it works for you can you please provide a screen shot what you choose in the headers and the body probably I missing something...

Comment: @JohnJerrby as I told you I'm using `CocoaRestClient` just give me a few minutes and I'll try with `postman` to check the right settings

Comment: @JohnJerrby `Postman` sets the `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary...` when you put a file in the body as `form-data`, so you don't need to set `multipart/form-data` manually. your issue seems to be another

Comment: @mithril_knight- I've just this file with the code I provided and I use postman as I put in the question can you provide the screen shot of postman as answer.any idea what it can be?